# React Link onClick not leveraging current params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's same i'm rendering some React Component and its render looks like this:

```
render(){
  let links = [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000].map((num) => {
    return(
      <Link key={num} onClick={this.showParams.bind(this)} to={`/somePath/${num}`}>{num}</Link>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>{links}</div>
  )
}
```

And I have the following function defined in the same component:

```
showParams(){
  console.log(this.props.params);
}
```

Whenever I click a link, it's logging what the params value was before the link was clicked, not after the link was clicked. How can I get my react component to access the `props.params` garnered from this link itself. Or should I be taking a completely different approach. It does feel a little off that I need an `onClick`(i eventually want to reset the state with this new parameter, that seems like something the Link component should do inherently).

If it helps here's the part of my router that's pertinent:

```
<Route path='/somePath/:num' component={someComponent} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6

Use an arrow function:

```
return (
  <th value={column} onClick={() => this.handleSort(column)}>{column}</th>
);
```

ES5

You can use .bind to pass the parameter you want:

```
return (
  <th value={column} onClick={that.handleSort.bind(that, column)}>{column}</th>
);
```

Comment: thanks i ended up using an arrow function. just felt a bit hacky, feel like i should be able to use parameters